# Cmake: Getting the location of a target from the command line

Tags: cmake

At the moment I believe I need to get the location of a target's output from the command line of Cmake (after it's built).

Or, maybe I need to script CMake to allow a process to be run on a target (after it's built).

Our basic flow will be:

1. code
2. build
3. debug
4. build
5. profile
6. build
7. etc.

and I want to make this more easily done from one place on the command line.

At the moment, we're planning on putting a python front end to our build stuff (since it's a heterogenous SoC with multiple processors, we can't have a single configuration due to multiple compilers required) so some scripting on the outside isn't a big deal.

I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
  cmake <configuration stuff> 
  build.py <target>
  debug.py <target>
  profile.py <target>
```

without the developer having to know exactly where the target's binary is.  (FYI, these things are more complicated than just calling gdb or whatever, so they do require a script to make it happen from the command line via 3rd party tools)

Is this easily accomplishable?   Or do I need to script up some stuff in Cmake to output the required information to a file during configuration and query that file after the fact?

Any guidance or help accomplishing my goal is greatly appreciated.

edit:   trying to be more pointed in my questioning:

After I've configured using cmake.   is there a way from the build directory to run cmake again to query the cache/buildsystem/whatever to find out where a target's output would be.

for example:

```
./source
   /modules
     /module1
        /submodule1
            /test1
        /submodule2
            /test1
     /module2
        /test1
     /module3
        /test1
```

I go into my build directory, do `cmake -S .. -B . <etc>`

I now have a tree filled with makefiles and other stuff.

If i do make, that tree gets populated with build artifacts that roughly mirrors the source tree (at least it does in my experience)

if I do `make help` it outputs a bunch of targets by name.

```
module1
submodule1
submodule1_test1
submodule2
submodule2_test1
```

etc.

Now, I want to know where submodule1_test1's executable is without having to know that its parent is module1.  Can I, at this point, run cmake and query the cache/buildsystem to get the location of that named target?

If I can't, I can manage it myself by forming a "database" at configure time.  It's not a problem.  I just was hoping cmake kept that information around for querying at a later time in its cache or whatever.

Comment: `Is this easily accomplishable?` yes `do I need to script up some stuff in Cmake to output the required information to a file during configuration` you could `query that file after the fact?` you could do that also. You could do just `add_custom_command(COMMAND echo $<TARGET_FILE:the_target>)`. What have you tried? Did it work? What research did you do? But executables are put inside `CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` so the thing is that __you__ are deciding during `cmake <configuration stuff>` where it goes.

Comment: @KamilCuk Ok, perhaps a bit more targetted question:   is there something, after the config and build are completed, that I can do to do `cmake <something> MyTarget` and have it echo the path to stdout?   I'm not seeing how add_custom_command() helps me in this regard.

Comment: `cmake` is for configuring things. The location of `MyTarget` changes depending on what you put in `<something>`. The point is that _you_ have control over where `MyTarget` executable goes. If you do `cmake .` in the dir where `CMakeLists.txt` is, then `MyTarget` will be inside that dir. I don't understand. You decide where you want `MyTarget` when you run `cmake`. If you want for example `MyTarget` to be in `/tmp/bin`, then just `cmake -DCMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=/tmp/bin .` to configure the project. If the `RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` is not set, then just the dir where CMakeCache is used

Comment: I know cmake is for configuring things.   I'm just wondering if I can query the configuration after its done to get the details for use outside the build system.   see my edit

Comment: A little progress.    add_custom_target(path-${mytarget} COMMAND echo $<TARGET_FILE:${mytarget} DEPENDS ${mytarget})  lets me do 'make path-submodule1' and it echos the full path to the target.  And even builds the target if it's not built yet.   It does 'dirty' the output with the progress information (which I DO want, usually), but the information is there.  It also dirties the `make help` list, but I guess there's no helping that.

Comment: Yes. Now just remove `DEPENDS`. Why would printing the target name depend on the target? Unless you want it to.

Comment: @KamilCuk  even without the DEPENDS it still builds the target and its dependencies.  weird.

Answer (score 2):

When you first generate your project with CMake, it creates a CMakeCache.txt file which has all the variables cache variables from your project. You can use Python to parse it and find the *project_name_BINARY_DIR* variable. That will be your build destination root. From that point on, you can use Python to recursively check the subdirectories for test executables if they all have a standard naming pattern such as FooTests.exe.

Alternatively, if you use the [set cache](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.16/command/set.html#set-cache-entry) command, it should also get added to the CMakeCache.txt.